# How to import an image and make a title at a check box in Java?

Tags: java, image, jcheckbox

I have been trying to create the Facebook login page and I cannot import the image I want. When I run the code at first it opens with all the features I made but the picture fails to show up, but when I minimize/maximize it shows perfectly where I put it. How can I display it without minimizing/maximizing it? Also I have a couple of with some elements which I do not want to be selected in the check boxes?

This is part of my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class art extends Canvas{
public static String emri;
public static String mbiemri;
public static JFrame f1;

public static JButton b9;
public static JButton b12;
public static JButton b13;
public static JButton b15;
public static JButton b16;
public static JButton b17;
public static JButton b18;
public static JButton b19;
public static JButton b20;
public static JButton b21;
public static JButton b22;
public static JButton b23;
public static JButton b24;
public static JButton b25;
public static JButton b26;
public static JButton b27;
public static JButton b28;
public static JButton b29;
public static JButton b30;
public static JButton b31;;



public static JComboBox<String> m4;


public static JTextArea k1;
public static JTextArea k2;

public static JFrame f;
public static JButton b;
public static JButton a;
public static JTextArea c;
public static JTextArea d;
public static JCheckBox ch;
public static JTextArea ch1;
public static JTextArea ch2;
public static JTextArea ch3;
public static JTextArea ch4;
public static JComboBox<String> m;
public static JComboBox<String> m1;
public static JComboBox<String> m2;
public static JComboBox<String> m3;
public static JButton b1;
public static JButton b2;
public static Image p;
public static Image p1;
public static Image p2;
public static Image p3;
public static Image p4;
public static Image p5;

public static JFrame e1;
public static JFrame e;
public static JPanel z;
public static JPanel z1;
public static JLabel w;
public static JLabel w1;
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(new Color(59, 89, 182));
    g.fillRect(0,0 , 1350, 150);

    g.setColor(new Color(230,230,230));
    g.fillRect( 0,150 , 1350, 580);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 47));
    g.drawString("facebook", 60, 120);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
    g.drawString("Email", 630, 45);
    g.fillRect(630, 50, 210, 25);
    g.drawString("Password", 875, 45);
    g.fillRect(875, 50, 210, 25);


    g.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    g.setColor(new Color(59,89,182));
    g.drawString("First name:", 700, 320);
    g.drawLine(800, 300, 1100, 300);
    g.drawLine(800, 300, 800, 330);
    g.drawLine(800, 330, 1100, 330);
    g.drawLine(1100, 300, 1100, 330);

    g.drawString("Last name:", 700, 355);
    g.drawLine(800, 335, 1100, 335);
    g.drawLine(800, 335, 800, 365);
    g.drawLine(800, 365, 1100, 365);
    g.drawLine(1100, 335, 1100, 365);

    g.drawString("Your Email:", 700, 390);
    g.drawLine(800, 370, 1100, 370);
    g.drawLine(800, 370, 800, 400);
    g.drawLine(800, 400, 1100, 400);
    g.drawLine(1100, 370, 1100, 400);


    g.drawString("New Password:", 670, 425);
    g.drawLine(800, 405, 1100, 405);
    g.drawLine(800, 405, 800, 435);
    g.drawLine(800, 435, 1100, 435);
    g.drawLine(1100, 405, 1100, 435);

    g.drawString("I am:", 745, 460);
    g.drawString("Birthday:", 720, 495);

    g.setColor(new Color(59, 89, 182));
    g.setFont(new Font("Luciana Grande",Font.BOLD, 20));
    g.drawString("Sign UP", 600, 250);
    g.drawString("Facebook helps you connect and share with", 60, 240);
    g.drawString("the people in your life.", 60, 270);


    g.setFont(new Font("Luciana Grande",Font.PLAIN, 20));
    g.drawString("it's free (and alwyas will be)",600, 280);

    g.setColor(new Color(59,89,192));
    g.drawLine(630, 605, 1250, 605);
    g.drawString("Create a page", 710, 630);

    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.drawString("for a celebrity, band or business.",843, 630);

    g.drawImage(p, 60, 330, 400, 170, null);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    art x = new art();
    f  = new JFrame();
    f1= new JFrame();
    e= new JFrame();
    e1= new JFrame();
    b  = new JButton();
    a  = new JButton();
    b1 = new JButton();
    b2 = new JButton();
    b9= new JButton();
    b12= new JButton();
    b13 = new JButton();
    b15 = new JButton();
    b16 = new JButton();
    b17 = new JButton();
    b18 = new JButton();
    b19 = new JButton();
    b20 = new JButton();
    b21 = new JButton();
    b22 = new JButton();
    b23 = new JButton();
    b23 = new JButton();
    b24 = new JButton();
    b25 = new JButton();
    b26 = new JButton();
    b27 = new JButton();
    b28 = new JButton();
    b29 = new JButton();
    b30 = new JButton();
    b31 = new JButton();

    c= new JTextArea();
    d= new JTextArea();
    ch= new JCheckBox();    
    ch1= new JTextArea();
    ch2= new JTextArea();
    ch3= new JTextArea();
    ch4= new JTextArea();
    k1= new JTextArea();
    k2 = new JTextArea();

    m1= new JComboBox<String>();
    m= new JComboBox<String>();
    m2=new JComboBox<String>();
    m3=new JComboBox<String>();
    m4= new JComboBox<String>();


    z= new JPanel();
    z1= new JPanel();
    w= new JLabel();
    w1= new JLabel();

    p = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("image.jpeg");

    m4.addItem("Friends");
    m4.addItem("Only me");
    m4.addItem("Everyone");




    m1.addItem("Month:");
    m1.addItem("January");
    m1.addItem("February");
    m1.addItem("March");
    m1.addItem("April");
    m1.addItem("May");
    m1.addItem("June");
    m1.addItem("July");
    m1.addItem("September");
    m1.addItem("October");
    m1.addItem("November");
    m1.addItem("December");
    m1.addItemListener(null);
    m1.setBounds(800,477, 83,20);

    m2.addItem("Day:");
    m2.addItem("1");
    m2.addItem("2");
    m2.addItem("3");
    m2.addItem("4");
    m2.addItem("5");
    m2.addItem("6");
    m2.addItem("7");
    m2.addItem("8");
    m2.addItem("9");
    m2.addItem("10");
    m2.addItem("11");
    m2.addItem("12");
    m2.addItem("13");
    m2.addItem("14");
    m2.addItem("15");
    m2.addItem("16");
    m2.addItem("17");
    m2.addItem("18");
    m2.addItem("19");
    m2.addItem("20");
    m2.addItem("21");
    m2.addItem("22");
    m2.addItem("23");
    m2.addItem("24");
    m2.addItem("25");
    m2.addItem("26");
    m2.addItem("27");
    m2.addItem("28");
    m2.addItem("29");
    m2.addItem("30");
    m2.addItemListener(null);
    m2.setBounds(900, 477, 50, 20);

    m3.addItem("Year:");
    m3.addItem("2017");
    m3.addItem("2016");
    m3.addItem("2015");
    m3.addItem("2014");
    m3.addItem("2013");
    m3.addItem("2012");
    m3.addItem("2011");
    m3.addItem("2010");
    m3.addItem("2009");
    m3.addItem("2008");
    m3.addItem("2007");
    m3.addItem("2006");
    m3.addItem("2005");
    m3.addItem("2004");
    m3.addItem("2003");
    m3.addItem("2002");
    m3.addItem("2001");
    m3.addItem("2000");
    m3.addItem("1999");
    m3.addItem("1998");
    m3.addItem("1997");
    m3.addItem("1996");
    m3.addItem("1995");
    m3.addItem("1994");
    m3.addItem("1993");
    m3.addItem("1992");
    m3.addItem("1991");
    m3.addItem("1990");
    m3.addItem("1900");
    m3.addItemListener(null);
    m3.setBounds(970, 477, 60, 20);

    m.addItem("Select sex:");
    m.addItem("Male");
    m.addItem("Female");
    m.addItemListener(null);
    m.setBounds(800, 445, 90, 20);

    a.setText("Forgot your password?");
    a.setBackground(new Color(59, 89, 182));
    a.setForeground(Color.white);
    a.setBounds(875, 103, 200, 20);

    b.setText("login");
    b.setBackground(new Color(59, 89, 182));
    b.setForeground(Color.white);
    b.setFocusPainted(true);
    b.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
    b.setBounds(1120, 49, 100, 25);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e){
            String v1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Vendosni emrin:");
            emri= new String(v1).toString();
            String v2= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Vendosni mbiemrin:");
            mbiemri= new String(v2).toString();
            b9.setBounds(400, 400, 50, 40);

            m4.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            m4.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18)); 
            m4.setBounds(420, 268, 100, 30);


            b23.setBackground(new Color(59,89,182));
            b23.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            b23.setText("Post");
            b23.setBounds(525, 268, 89, 30);

            b24.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b24.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18)); 
            b24.setText("Search");
            b24.setBounds(525, 30, 99, 30);

            b25.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b25.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18)); 
            b25.setText("Send Friend Request");
            b25.setBounds(730, 250, 180, 30);

            b26.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b26.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18)); 
            b26.setText("Like");
            b26.setBounds(730, 430, 60, 30);

            b27.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b27.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18)); 
            b27.setText("Join");
            b27.setBounds(730, 620, 60, 30);

            b28.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b28.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18)); 
            b28.setText("Chat(230)");
            b28.setBounds(1100, 648, 200, 30);

            b29.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b29.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18)); 
            b29.setText("Like");
            b29.setBounds(250, 630, 70, 20);
            b30.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b30.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18)); 
            b30.setText("Comment");
            b30.setBounds(321, 630, 95, 20);
            b31.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b31.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18)); 
            b31.setText("Share");
            b31.setBounds(402, 630, 70, 20);

            artvazhdim a = new artvazhdim();

            k1.setBounds(131, 32, 200, 20);
            k2.setBounds(192, 185, 200, 30);

            b17.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b17.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18));
            b17.setText(emri + " " +mbiemri);
            b17.setBounds(18, 108, 160, 30);

            b18.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b18.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18));
            b18.setText("News Feed");
            b18.setBounds(18, 145, 100, 20);

            b19.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b19.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18));
            b19.setText("Messages");
            b19.setBounds(18, 172, 105, 20);

            b20.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b20.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18));
            b20.setText("Groups");
            b20.setBounds(18, 295, 80, 20);

            b21.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b21.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18));
            b21.setText("Friend Lists");
            b21.setBounds(18, 330, 120, 20);

            b22.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b22.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18));
            b22.setText("Pokes");
            b22.setBounds(18, 365, 80, 20);


            f1.getContentPane().add(a);
            b9.setBackground(new Color(59,89,182));
            b9.setForeground(Color.white);
            b9.setBounds(899, 30, 100, 30);
            b9.setText(emri);
            b12.setBackground(new Color(59,89,182));
            b12.setForeground(Color.white);
            b12.setText("Profile");
            b12.setBounds(1004, 30, 80, 30);
            b13.setBackground(new Color(59,89,182));
            b13.setForeground(Color.white);
            b13.setText("logout");
            b13.setBounds(1088, 30, 70, 30);
            b13.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent k){
                    f1.setVisible(false);
                    f.setVisible(true);

                }

            });
            b15.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b15.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18));
            b15.setText("Photo/video");
            b15.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,9));
            b15.setBounds(198, 145, 100, 20);

            b16.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
            b16.setForeground(new Color(59,89,18));
            b16.setText("Photo/video Album");
            b16.setBounds(303, 145, 100, 20);


            f1.add(m4);
            f1.add(b19);
            f1.add(b20);
            f1.add(b21);
            f1.add(b24);
            f1.add(b22);
            f1.add(b28);
            f1.add(b16);
            f1.add(b30);
            f1.add(b31);
            f1.add(b17);
            f1.add(b13);
            f1.add(b23);
            f1.add(b25);
            f1.add(b29);
            f1.add(b26);
            f1.add(b27);
            f1.add(b15);
            f1.add(b12);
            f1.add(b9);
            f1.add(k1);
            f1.add(b18);
            f1.add(k2);
            f1.add(a);
            f1.setSize(1350, 720);



            f1.setVisible(true);
            f.setVisible(false);

        }

    });




    b1.setText("Why do i need to provide this?");
    b1.setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
    b1.setForeground(new Color(59,89,182));
    b1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
    b1.setBounds(800, 500, 270, 35);

    b2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    b2.setText("Sign up");
    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args0){
            z1.setBackground( new Color(59,89,182));
            w1.setText("Congratulations, you are the newest member on Facebook!!");
            w1.setForeground(Color.white);
            w1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,30));
            w1.setBounds(200,100,1000,200);
            e1.add(w1);

            e1.add(z1);
            e1.setSize(1350,720);
            e1.setVisible(true);


        }
    });
    b2.setBackground(Color.green);
    b2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    b2.setBounds(800, 560, 100, 40);

    c.setBounds(631, 54, 208, 20);
    ch1.setBackground(new  Color(230,230,230));
    ch2.setBackground(new  Color(230,230,230));
    ch3.setBackground(new  Color(230,230,230));
    ch4.setBackground(new  Color(230,230,230));
    ch1.setBounds(801, 307, 299, 22);
    ch2.setBounds(801, 342, 299, 22);
    ch3.setBounds(801, 377, 299, 22);
    ch4.setBounds(801, 412, 299, 22);

    d.setBounds(876, 54, 208, 20);

    ch.setBounds(626, 76, 135 , 70);
    ch.setText("Keep me logged in");
    ch.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    ch.setBackground(new Color(59, 89, 182));

    f.setSize(1350, 720);
    f.repaint();
    f.revalidate();


    f.add(b2);
    f.add(b1);
    f.add(m3);
    f.add(m2);
    f.add(m1);
    f.add(m);
    f.add(ch2);
    f.add(ch3);
    f.add(ch4);
    f.add(ch1);
    f.add(a);
    f.add(ch);
    f.add(d);
    f.add(c);
    f.add(b);
    f.add(x);

    f.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Toolkit.createImage() is asynchronous, so your image may not be fully loaded at the time you call drawImage(). You need either to provide an ImageObserver:

```
g.drawImage(p, 60, 330, 400, 170, this);
```

or (preferrably) to use ImageIO for loading image:

```
p = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpeg"));
```

Also, you shouldn't mix AWT (Canvas) and Swing components. Actually, you shouldn't use AWT at all (it's old and heavy); use JPanel for drawing instead.